# Meteor client / server side collections behaviour

Tags: meteor

I'm slightly confused about the availability of a collections, and exactly what happens when I use them in different places. I have a collection at `/imports/api/clubs` When I use it in my `Meteor.methods` it works fine. If I then import it into say a template file `/imports/ui/pages/new_club.js` and insert something into it, will it update the local cache only? Is the local collection reactive, i.e. will my helpers re-run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Meteor *collection* contains 0-N *documents*. A *collection* can be *managed* or *unmanaged*.

A *managed* collection:

- is persisted via MongoDB on a server. It will survive either the client or the server stopping.
- Exists only on the *server* unless it is *published* to the client via either the *autopublish* package or via one or more *publications*
- the server automatically has read-write access to *all* documents in the collection
- publications can be used to restrict the subset of the documents (both which documents and which keys) are available to any particular client.
- changes to a collection on the server are automatically and asynchronously propagated to the affected client(s) via Meteor's DDP protocol which normally runs over WebSocket.
- if changes are made to a collection from the client, the client's view is immediately updated (called an "optimistic update", part of Meteor's "latency compensation") and then the server attempts to make the same change. The server version ultimately "wins" in that changes from the server are asynchronously re-propagated back to the affected client(s).

An *unmanaged* collection:

- exists only on the client
- can be written to and read from only from the client
- is not shared between clients

On the server side Meteor has access to the full MongoDB API. On the client side, Meteor has implemented "minimongo" which presents a restricted API. Minimongo is notably missing mongodb's *aggregation framework* as well as geo-queries.

Finally, to answer your specific question: yes, collections are *reactive* to changes made anywhere, either on the client you're on, by the server, or initiated on someone else's client